# How to get a short data type value as input

Tags: c#, input, short

I need to get a short data type value as a input in C# Console Application. I heard that, its easy to get input in int, string,etc in C#. But I have to get a short data type value as a input. Please help me.
Thanks !!

Comment: I'm curious to know what you have actually tried so far.

Comment: I tried to see a function similar to ToInt16, ToDouble, ToString.But I couldn't find it for short. So I made a request.

Comment: `short` is an alias for `Int16`. Most of the basic types have shorthand aliases for ease of use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287910%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
short s;
if(short.TryParse(input, out s))
{
    //use s
}
else
{
    //invalid input
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its really nice to have a clearly understandable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Console.ReadLine()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) and apply check on it that if given value is not short then you ask for input again.

```
string inputForShort = Console.ReadLine();
short result=0;
bool shortGiven = false;
do { 
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter short value");
       inputForShort = Console.ReadLine();
       shortGiven = short.TryParse(inputForShort , out result);           

} while (!shortGiven);   

Console.WriteLine("You entered short value" + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var Input = Console.ReadLine();
Short ShortInput;
Int16.TryParse(Input,out ShortInput);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this in Visual Basic ?